# how can suppressed exception in the 'try' block be retrieved?

Tags: java, exception

From Java 7, we can use the try-with-resources statement:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

if `br.readLine()` and `br.close()` **both throw exceptions**, `readFirstLineFromFile` will **throw** the exception from the **try block** (the exception of `br.readLine()` ), and the exception from the **implicit finally block** of the try-with-resources statement (the exception of `br.close()` ) will be **suppressed.**

In this case, we can **retrieve** suppressed exceptions from the **implicit finally block** by calling the `getSuppresed` method **from** the exception of the **try block** like this:

```
try {   
    readFirstLineFromFile("Some path here..."); // this is the method using try-with-resources statement
}   catch (IOException e) {     // this is the exception from the try block  
    Throwable[] suppressed = e.getSuppressed();
    for (Throwable t : suppressed) {
        // Check t's type and decide on action to be taken
    }
}
```

But suppose we have to work with a method written with an older version than Java 7, in which the finally block is used:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock(String path) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) br.close();
    }
}
```

then if `br.readLine()` and `br.close()` once again **both throw exceptions**, the situation will be reversed. The method `readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock` will **throw** the exception from the **finally block** (the exception of `br.close()` ), 
and the exception from the **try block** (the exception of `br.readLine()` ) will be **suppressed.**

So my question here is: how can we **retrieve** the **suppressed exceptions** from the **try block** in the second case?

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, basically. The suppressed exception is lost if `br.close()` throws.

The closest you could come would be to have a `catch` block which assigns the value to a locla variable:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock(String path) throws IOException {
    IOException exception = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    try {
      return br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      exception = e;
    } finally {
      try {
        if (br != null) br.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // Both the original call and close failed. Eek!
        // Decide what you want to do here...
      }
      // close succeeded, but we already had an exception
      if (exception != null) {
        throw exception;
      }
    }
}
```

... but this *only* handles `IOException` (rather than any unchecked exceptions) and is horribly messy.

Comment: I'm gonna add "JonSkeet" to the followed TAGS... ^^

Answer (score 1):

> the exception from the **try block** (the exception of br.readLine() ) will be **suppressed.**

That's not quite correct. The Java Language Specification [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2):

> - If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the run-time type of V is not assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement, then the finally block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>     - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly because of a throw of the value V.
>     - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and the throw of value V is discarded and forgotten).

That is, the exception is "discarded and forgotten", not merely suppressed.

BTW, as the [mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed%28java.lang.Throwable%29) for attaching a suppressed exception to another exception has been introduced in Java 7, there was no general support for this in Java 6. Therefore, there is no way code targeting Java 6 can make use of that feature.